# Elasticsearch (Java) - Integration tests

Tags: java, elasticsearch, integration-testing

I use Java 8, Elasticsearch High level client 6.1.1 and Maven and want to write some integration tests.
Here my java class for tests:

```
@ESIntegTestCase.ClusterScope(scope = ESIntegTestCase.Scope.SUITE, numDataNodes=1)
public class ElasticSearchServiceITest extends ESIntegTestCase {
}
```

I have added dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I try to run my  test - I see cuch error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath

```
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:190)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$2.run(RandomizedRunner.java:592)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context information for thread: Thread[id=29, name=Thread-6, state=RUNNABLE, group=TGRP-ElasticSearchServiceITest]. Is this thread running under a class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner runner context? Add @RunWith(class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class) to your test class. Make sure your code accesses random contexts within @BeforeClass and @AfterClass boundary (for example, static test class initializers are not permitted to access random contexts).
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedContext.context(RandomizedContext.java:248)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedContext.current(RandomizedContext.java:134)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.augmentStackTrace(RandomizedRunner.java:1848)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RunnerThreadGroup.uncaughtException(RunnerThreadGroup.java:20)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1959)
```

What I'm doing wrong? I haven't added any functionality but get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by running the tests with `tests.security.manager=false` set. You can also update your java policy files (see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22689)